# Rails: How to see if request.referrer was a GET or POST?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I can't find any way to do this, but it seems *remotely possible* that there might be a way to determine (from a controller) not merely the URL of `request.referrer` but also the request method—not of the current `request` object, but of the method used to reach `request.referer`.

The goal is to determine whether redirecting back to `request.referrer` is safe or not.

(But in the interest of keeping *problems* separate from *questions*, I will ask [a separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54354804/241142) about a separate approach to solving the problem, and link to it from this one.)

Comment: As far as I can tell the only way to do this is to capture the method earlier and pass that information into the controller.  Otherwise the URL seems to be the only thing available about the refer(r)er that you have in the request object...

Comment: if your app follows a proper redirect after post pattern, it's safe to assume that you can redirect to :back

Comment: @phoet: that would be great, but I'm working on an inherited app with a "wizard" that POSTs to the same URL over and over until it's complete. It doesn't persist anything until the very last step of the wizard, so creating GETable urls would require a complete refactoring of the wizard.  Certain (developer-only) actions taken in the middle of the wizard require redirecting and I want to avoid a 404.  If end users were subjected to this annoyance I would feel such refactoring would be justified, but it's just me and one other person.  So redirecting to "/" is sufficient.